# Java procss terminated with long log

Tags: java

I wrote an application in java, it starts docker to execute commands. but when I begin to run the java application, it is terminated unexpectedly, and I can't find the reason, please someone tell me why???

The docker command is:

```
docker run --dns=127.0.0.1 --name abc -v abc:/test appium su user -c /test/run.sh
```

The environments are:

My server configuration is :

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (with kernel 4.0.2-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64)
```

The java version is :

```
java version "1.6.0_37"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.12-b01, mixed mode)
```

The docker version is :

```
Docker version 1.7.0, build 0baf609
```

Here is the following logs :

```
*** glibc detected *** ./java: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00007fe334006530 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3d48275e66]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3d482789b3]
/usr/alibaba/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so(+0x5b46)[0x7fe3a2648b46]
/usr/alibaba/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so(Java_java_net_NetworkInterface_getAll+0x8c)[0x7fe3a264806c]
[0x7fe3a84b0eee]
======= Memory map: ========
40000000-40009000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 2632610                            /usr/alibaba/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java
40108000-4010a000 rwxp 00008000 08:02 2632610                            /usr/alibaba/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java
412e6000-41307000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
77dc00000-77fb40000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
77fb40000-782e00000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
782e00000-788170000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
788170000-7d64b0000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7d64b0000-7d8660000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7d8660000-7d8e60000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7d8e60000-800000000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
3d47e00000-3d47e20000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1704030                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3d4801f000-3d48020000 r-xp 0001f000 08:02 1704030                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3d48020000-3d48021000 rwxp 00020000 08:02 1704030                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3d48021000-3d48022000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
3d48200000-3d4838a000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1704058                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3d4838a000-3d4858a000 ---p 0018a000 08:02 1704058                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3d4858a000-3d4858e000 r-xp 0018a000 08:02 1704058                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3d4858e000-3d4858f000 rwxp 0018e000 08:02 1704058                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3d4858f000-3d48594000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
3d48600000-3d48617000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1703999                        /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3d48617000-3d48817000 ---p 00017000 08:02 1703999                        /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3d48817000-3d48818000 r-xp 00017000 08:02 1703999                        /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3d48818000-3d48819000 rwxp 00018000 08:02 1703999                        /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3d48819000-3d4881d000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
3d48a00000-3d48a02000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1704178                        /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
3d48a02000-3d48c02000 ---p 00002000 08:02 1704178                        /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
3d48c02000-3d48c03000 r-xp 00002000 08:02 1704178                        /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
3d48c03000-3d48c04000 rwxp 00003000 08:02 1704178                        /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
3d48e00000-3d48e07000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1703938                        /lib64/librt-2.12.so
3d48e07000-3d49006000 ---p 00007000 08:02 1703938                        /lib64/librt-2.12.so
3d49006000-3d49007000 r-xp 00006000 08:02 1703938                        /lib64/librt-2.12.so
3d49007000-3d49008000 rwxp 00007000 08:02 1703938                        /lib64/librt-2.12.so
3d49600000-3d49683000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1704159                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3d49683000-3d49882000 ---p 00083000 08:02 1704159                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3d49882000-3d49883000 r-xp 00082000 08:02 1704159                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3d49883000-3d49884000 rwxp 00083000 08:02 1704159                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3d4a200000-3d4a216000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1704024                        /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
3d4a216000-3d4a416000 ---p 00016000 08:02 1704024                        /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
3d4a416000-3d4a417000 r-xp 00016000 08:02 1704024                        /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
3d4a417000-3d4a418000 rwxp 00017000 08:02 1704024                        /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
3d4a418000-3d4a41a000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
3d4a600000-3d4a616000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1704182                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
3d4a616000-3d4a815000 ---p 00016000 08:02 1704182                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
3d4a815000-3d4a816000 rwxp 00015000 08:02 1704182                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
3d4ca00000-3d4ca16000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1704297                        /lib64/libnsl-2.12.so
3d4ca16000-3d4cc15000 ---p 00016000 08:02 1704297                        /lib64/libnsl-2.12.so
3d4cc15000-3d4cc16000 r-xp 00015000 08:02 1704297                        /lib64/libnsl-2.12.so
3d4cc16000-3d4cc17000 rwxp 00016000 08:02 1704297                        /lib64/libnsl-2.12.so
3d4cc17000-3d4cc19000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe320000000-7fe32002e000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe32002e000-7fe324000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe324000000-7fe324023000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe324023000-7fe328000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe328000000-7fe328581000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe328581000-7fe32c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe32c000000-7fe32c021000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe32c021000-7fe330000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe330000000-7fe330021000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe330021000-7fe334000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe334000000-7fe334023000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe334023000-7fe338000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe338000000-7fe338091000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe338091000-7fe33c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe33c000000-7fe33c021000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe33c021000-7fe340000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe340000000-7fe340021000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe340021000-7fe344000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe344000000-7fe344021000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe344021000-7fe348000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe348000000-7fe34808e000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe34808e000-7fe34c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe34c000000-7fe34c021000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe34c021000-7fe350000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe350000000-7fe350021000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe350021000-7fe354000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe354000000-7fe3540a0000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe3540a0000-7fe358000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe358000000-7fe358021000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe358021000-7fe35c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe35c000000-7fe35c069000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe35c069000-7fe360000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe360000000-7fe360021000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe360021000-7fe364000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe364000000-7fe3640b2000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe3640b2000-7fe368000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe368000000-7fe368021000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe368021000-7fe36c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe36c000000-7fe36c021000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe36c021000-7fe370000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe370000000-7fe372991000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe372991000-7fe374000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe374000000-7fe376a6d000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe376a6d000-7fe378000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe378000000-7fe3780f5000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe3780f5000-7fe37c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37c654000-7fe37c657000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37c657000-7fe37c755000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37c755000-7fe37c758000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37c758000-7fe37c856000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:29015]
7fe37c856000-7fe37c859000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37c859000-7fe37c957000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37c957000-7fe37c95a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37c95a000-7fe37ca58000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28969]
7fe37ca58000-7fe37ca5b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37ca5b000-7fe37cb59000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28968]
7fe37cb59000-7fe37cb5c000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37cb5c000-7fe37cc5a000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28967]
7fe37cc5a000-7fe37cc5d000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37cc5d000-7fe37cd5b000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28966]
7fe37cd5b000-7fe37cd5e000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37cd5e000-7fe37ce5c000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28965]
7fe37ce5c000-7fe37ce5f000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37ce5f000-7fe37cf5d000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28964]
7fe37cf5d000-7fe37cf60000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37cf60000-7fe37d05e000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28963]
7fe37d05e000-7fe37d061000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37d061000-7fe37d15f000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28961]
7fe37d15f000-7fe37d162000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37d162000-7fe37d260000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28960]
7fe37d260000-7fe37d263000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37d263000-7fe37d361000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28962]
7fe37d361000-7fe37d364000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37d364000-7fe37d462000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28783]
7fe37d462000-7fe37d465000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37d465000-7fe37d563000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28761]
7fe37d563000-7fe37d566000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37d566000-7fe37d664000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28752]
7fe37d664000-7fe37d667000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37d667000-7fe37d765000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28742]
7fe37d765000-7fe37d768000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37d768000-7fe37d866000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28760]
7fe37d866000-7fe37d869000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37d869000-7fe37d967000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28758]
7fe37d967000-7fe37d96a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37d96a000-7fe37da68000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28716]
7fe37da68000-7fe37da6b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37da6b000-7fe37db69000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28701]
7fe37db69000-7fe37db6c000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37db6c000-7fe37dc6a000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28719]
7fe37dc6a000-7fe37dc6d000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37dc6d000-7fe37dd6b000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28718]
7fe37dd6b000-7fe37dd6e000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37dd6e000-7fe37de6c000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28711]
7fe37de6c000-7fe37de6f000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37de6f000-7fe37df6d000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28662]
7fe37df6d000-7fe37df70000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37df70000-7fe37e06e000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28661]
7fe37e06e000-7fe37e071000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe37e071000-7fe37e16f000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28660]
7fe37e16f000-7fe384000000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 2373769                    /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7fe384000000-7fe384021000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe384021000-7fe388000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe388000000-7fe388021000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe388021000-7fe38c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe38c000000-7fe38c021000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe38c021000-7fe390000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe390000000-7fe390021000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe390021000-7fe394000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe394000000-7fe394021000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe394021000-7fe398000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe398000000-7fe398021000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe398021000-7fe39c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe39c000000-7fe39c026000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe39c026000-7fe3a0000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe3a00a5000-7fe3a00a8000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe3a00a8000-7fe3a01a6000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28659]
7fe3a01a6000-7fe3a01a9000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe3a01a9000-7fe3a02a7000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28658]
7fe3a02a7000-7fe3a02aa000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe3a02aa000-7fe3a03a8000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28657]
7fe3a03a8000-7fe3a03ab000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe3a03ab000-7fe3a04a9000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28656]
7fe3a04a9000-7fe3a04ac000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe3a04ac000-7fe3a05aa000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28655]
7fe3a05aa000-7fe3a05ad000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe3a05ad000-7fe3a06ab000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28653]
7fe3a06ab000-7fe3a06ae000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe3a06ae000-7fe3a07ac000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28585]
7fe3a07ac000-7fe3a07af000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe3a07af000-7fe3a08ad000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28631]
7fe3a08ad000-7fe3a08b0000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe3a08b0000-7fe3a09ae000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28392]
7fe3a09ae000-7fe3a09b1000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe3a09b1000-7fe3a0aaf000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28391]
7fe3a0aaf000-7fe3a0ab2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe3a0ab2000-7fe3a0bb0000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28390]
7fe3a0bb0000-7fe3a0bb3000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe3a0bb3000-7fe3a0cb1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28388]
7fe3a0cb1000-7fe3a0cb4000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe3a0cb4000-7fe3a0db2000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28384]
7fe3a0db2000-7fe3a0dca000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 2260594                    /tmp/jna7517025051621143906.tmp
7fe3a0dca000-7fe3a0ec9000 ---p 00018000 08:02 2260594                    /tmp/jna7517025051621143906.tmp
7fe3a0ec9000-7fe3a0eca000 rwxp 00017000 08:02 2260594                    /tmp/jna7517025051621143906.tmp
7fe3a0eca000-7fe3a0ecb000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe3a0ecb000-7fe3a0ece000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe3a0ece000-7fe3a0fcc000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28383]
7fe3a0fcc000-7fe3a0fcf000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe3a0fcf000-7fe3a10cd000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28389]
7fe3a10cd000-7fe3a10d0000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe3a10d0000-7fe3a11ce000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28381]
7fe3a11ce000-7fe3a11d1000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe3a11d1000-7fe3a12cf000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28380]
7fe3a1352000-7fe3a1355000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe3a1355000-7fe3a1453000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28654]
7fe3a1453000-7fe3a1456000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe3a1456000-7fe3a1554000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28643]
7fe3a1554000-7fe3a1557000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe3a1557000-7fe3a1655000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28645]
7fe3a1655000-7fe3a1658000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fe3a1658000-7fe3a1756000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack:28379]
7fe3a1756000-7fe3a175d000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 2632958                    /usr/alibaba/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/libnio.so
7fe3a175d000-7fe3a185c000 ---p 00007000 08:02 2632958                    /usr/alibaba/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/libnio.so
7fe3a185c000-7fe3a185e000 rwxp 00006000 08:02 2632958                    /usr/alibaba/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/libnio.so
7fe3a185e000-7fe3a1861000 Aborted
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're hitting this bug.

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7078386

I'd need some details about the OS configuration and the code to really know more, but I'd check that out and ensure you're using the most up to date JVM before anything else.

Comment: Hi, dbillz. Thank you very much for your reply! I've updated the question, added the OS configuration.  Do you have more ideas?